# jQuery events + HTML event attributes

Tags: jquery, events

I've got a form with an onsubmit attribute like this (which I *can't change*):

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this);">
```

I want to run another function, that needs to look at the return result of `validate()` and then possibly return `false` to prevent the form submitting.

Edit:

The contents of `onsubmit=""` could change, so I can't just write that code inside my own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with the following while writing the question, but I'm open to a better way:

```
// Grab the old function and remove it from the form
var oldSubmit = $('form').get(0).onsubmit;
$('form').get(0).onsubmit = null;

$('form').submit(function()
{
    // Use .call to make sure "this" is correct when the old function is run
    if (!oldSubmit.call($(this).get(0)))
        return false;

    // Do stuff

    return false;
});
```

Comment: You can just use "this" instead of $(this).get(0)

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the validate function with your own with something like this:

```
var oldValidate = validate;

var validate = function(form) {
  var value = oldValidate(form);
  //do your stuff here.
}
```